# how to find api endpoint to download data from objects

Tags: apex, rest-api, api

for some salesforce objects there is some api endpoints to download data from.
For example, for Document object we can use this api endpoint -> /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=ID

I realy struggled with that and a friend told me about that endpoint, i haven't found how can i know all api endpoints to download data from each salesforce standard object.

My questions are:

- I want to know all API endpoints to download data from each salesforce standard object (CollabGroup,....).
- I want to know how to find the endpoint to download data from a custom object that ends with __c

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here you can find all Salesforce endpoints:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_list.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_records.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve_get.htm
- https://github.com/forcedotcom/postman-salesforce-apis

Standard endpoint to get data have the same syntax for all objects: `/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/ObjectApiName/RecordId​`. You can execute it in workbench (#2)

2. I recommend https://workbench.developerforce.com/ to check the endpoint without additional authorization. Just log in with Salesforce credentials.
   [image: List item]

Comment: does they work for authenticated user ? I'm a pentester not a software developer. i already have a custom object + collabgroup all records but i asked if there is an api to download further data like for ContentDocument object (we can download the files themselves with the api endpoint).

Comment: Yep. I would say it works only for authenticated users. ContentDocument is a specific type of object (Represents a document that has been uploaded to a library in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files). Other objects are stored in a different way. As far as I know, you cannot download them as ContentVersion. You can only get data as (JSON [API], CSV [Export]).

Comment: ContentVersion have api endpoint to download like contentdoc, thanks for help. hope i anyone else have an answer